# Update sed command to remove white space at start and end of line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have existing sed command that I wrote to clean up a CSV. It removes spaces between commas in CSV file. I want to incorporate also removing white space at start and end of line without creating seperate sed command.

Here is the existing sed `sed -i 's/\s*,\s*/,/g'`. How can I incorporate also removing white space at start and end of line?

Thanks

Comment: Do your data entries contain any whitespaces or commas?

Answer (score -1):

You can put several commands in one sed call with -e:

```
sed -i -e 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' -e 's/^\s*//' -e 's/\s*$//'
```

should do the trick

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?